# How to auto format clockpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, clockpicker

I am using clockpicker(https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker) and I want to auto format time when type input field.

Here is the clockpicker code:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    var clockpicker = $(this).find('input').clockpicker({
    autoclose: true,
    twelvehour:true,
    afterDone: function() {
        clockpicker.val(clockpicker.val().slice(0,-2)+' '+clockpicker.val().slice(-2));
    }
});
```

This is the jsfiddle for demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/1e71occs/4/

For example jquery time picker provide an option to format. Here is the [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Time-Picker-Formatting-Plugin-Timepicker/) of example

**Expected OUTPUT**

if user enter:

```
1234 => 12:34 AM
1234p => 12:34 PM
```

How can I format entered time in clockpicker?

Thanks

Comment: Please read how you need to ask questions on SO. When jsFiddle provided, you need to add the code to your question.

Comment: And please provide what is the expected output format of the time?

Comment: @lolka_bolka: updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery allows to apply multiple plugins on each element.

You can use both clockpicker and timepicker as below

```
$('.container').each(function(){
     var clockpicker = $(this).find('input').clockpicker({
               autoclose: true,
               twelvehour:true,
               afterDone: function() {
                   clockpicker.val(clockpicker.val().slice(0,-2)+' '+clockpicker.val().slice(-2));
               }
     }).timepicker({dropdown:false,defaultTime:''});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

ClockPicker was designed for Bootstrap in the beginning. So Bootstrap (and jQuery) is the only dependency(s).

Since it only used .popover and some of .btn styles of Bootstrap, I picked these styles to build a jQuery plugin. Feel free to use jquery-* files instead of bootstrap-* , for non-bootstrap project.

https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/