# ClockPicker not a function (Google Appscript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-apps-script

I'm new to JQuery and bootstrap, and I am working on a clock widget served via Google Appscript. I've tried emulating the tutorial JSFiddle, but it just doesn't work for me. Even after reading other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676805/boot-strap-clock-picker-clockpicker-is-not-a-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685870/bootstrap-clock-picker-dynamic-input), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841066/how-to-auto-format-clockpicker), I still get this error in the Chrome developer console:

> input.clockpicker is not a function

I can't make a complete fiddle with GAS, but a very similar fiddle has already been made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ch7af2n/3/). It's exactly how I want it to work.

Here is my code:

Code.gs (mandatory for GAS webapps)

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('clock').evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 }
```

Clock.html:

```
<html >
 <head>
   <style>body {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 20px;
     }</style>

   <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquery-clockpicker.min.css').getContent(); ?>

   <title>Time Slot</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <input id="input-a" value="" data-default="20:48">
    <button type="button" id="button-a">Check the  minutes</button>
    <button type="button" id="button-b">Check the  hours</button>
     </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquery-clockpicker.min.js').getContent(); ?>

  <script>
  jQuery(function($) {
  var input = $('#input-a');
  input.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
  });

  // Manual operations
  $('#button-a').click(function(e){
  // Have to stop propagation here
  e.stopPropagation();
    input.clockpicker('show')
        .clockpicker('toggleView', 'minutes');
  });
  $('#button-b').click(function(e){
   // Have to stop propagation here
   e.stopPropagation();
   input.clockpicker('show')
        .clockpicker('toggleView', 'hours');
   });

   // The line below "closes" the document ready function
   });</script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

(GAS does not permit hosting of native JS files, but pulls the JS content from HTML pages fine on my other projects)

jquery-clockpicker.min.js.html (straight from the author):

```
/*!
 * ClockPicker v0.0.7 (http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)
 * Copyright 2014 Wang Shenwei.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */
!function(){function t(t){return document.createElementNS(p,t)}function i(t)        {return(10>t?"0":"")+t}function e(t){var i=++m+"";return t?t+i:i}function s(s,r)    {function p(t,i){var e=u.offset(),s=/^touch/.test(t.type),o=e.left+b,n=e.top+b,p=(s?    t.originalEvent.touches[0]:t).pageX-o,h=(s?t.originalEvent.touches[0]:t).pageY-    n,k=Math.sqrt(p*p+h*h),v=!1;if(!i||!(g-y>k||k>g+y)){t.preventDefault();var m=setTimeout(function(){c.addClass("clockpicker-moving")},200);l&&u.append(x.canvas),x.setHand(p,h,!i,!0),a.off(d).on(d,function(t){t.preventDefault();var i=/^touch/.test(t.type),e=(i?t.originalEvent.touches[0]:t).pageX-o,s=(i?t.originalEvent.touches[0]:t).pageY-n;(v||e!==p||s!==h)&&(v=!0,x.setHand(e,s,!1,!0))}),a.off(f).on(f,function(t){a.off(f),t.preventDefault();var e=/^touch/.test(t.type),s=(e?t.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]:t).pageX-o,l=(e?t.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]:t).pageY-n;(i||v)&&s===p&&l===h&&x.setHand(s,l),"hours"===x.currentView?x.toggleView("minutes",A/2):r.autoclose&&(x.minutesView.addClass("clockpicker-dial-out"),setTimeout(function(){x.done()},A/2)),u.prepend(j),clearTimeout(m),c.removeClass("clockpicker-moving"),a.off(d)})}}var h=n(V),u=h.find(".clockpicker-plate"),v=h.find(".clockpicker-hours"),m=h.find(".clockpicker-minutes"),T=h.find(".clockpicker-am-pm-block"),C="INPUT"===s.prop("tagName"),H=C?s:s.find("input"),P=s.find(".input-group-addon"),x=this;if(this.id=e("cp"),this.element=s,this.options=r,this.isAppended=!1,this.isShown=!1,this.currentView="hours",this.isInput=C,this.input=H,this.addon=P,this.popover=h,this.plate=u,this.hoursView=v,this.minutesView=m,this.amPmBlock=T,this.spanHours=h.find(".clockpicker-span-hours"),this.spanMinutes=h.find(".clockpicker-span-minutes"),this.spanAmPm=h.find(".clockpicker-span-am-pm"),this.amOrPm="PM",r.twelvehour){{var S=['<div class="clockpicker-am-pm-block">','<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button clockpicker-am-button">',"AM</button>",'<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button clockpicker-pm-button">',"PM</button>","</div>"].join("");n(S)}n('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button am-button">AM</button>').on("click",function(){x.amOrPm="AM",n(".clockpicker-span-am-pm").empty().append("AM")}).appendTo(this.amPmBlock),n('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button pm-button">PM</button>').on("click",function(){x.amOrPm="PM",n(".clockpicker-span-am-pm").empty().append("PM")}).appendTo(this.amPmBlock)}r.autoclose||n('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block clockpicker-button">'+r.donetext+"</button>").click(n.proxy(this.done,this)).appendTo(h),"top"!==r.placement&&"bottom"!==r.placement||"top"!==r.align&&"bottom"!==r.align||(r.align="left"),"left"!==r.placement&&"right"!==r.placement||"left"!==r.align&&"right"!==r.align||(r.align="top"),h.addClass(r.placement),h.addClass("clockpicker-align-"+r.align),this.spanHours.click(n.proxy(this.toggleView,this,"hours")),this.spanMinutes.click(n.proxy(this.toggleView,this,"minutes")),H.on("focus.clockpicker click.clockpicker",n.proxy(this.show,this)),P.on("click.clockpicker",n.proxy(this.toggle,this));var E,D,I,B,z=n('<div class="clockpicker-tick"></div>');if(r.twelvehour)for(E=1;13>E;E+=1)D=z.clone(),I=E/6*Math.PI,B=g,D.css("font-size","120%"),D.css({left:b+Math.sin(I)*B-y,top:b-Math.cos(I)*B-y}),D.html(0===E?"00":E),v.append(D),D.on(k,p);else for(E=0;24>E;E+=1){D=z.clone(),I=E/6*Math.PI;var O=E>0&&13>E;B=O?w:g,D.css({left:b+Math.sin(I)*B-y,top:b-Math.cos(I)*B-y}),O&&D.css("font-size","120%"),D.html(0===E?"00":E),v.append(D),D.on(k,p)}for(E=0;60>E;E+=5)D=z.clone(),I=E/30*Math.PI,D.css({left:b+Math.sin(I)*g-y,top:b-Math.cos(I)*g-y}),D.css("font-size","120%"),D.html(i(E)),m.append(D),D.on(k,p);if(u.on(k,function(t){0===n(t.target).closest(".clockpicker-tick").length&&p(t,!0)}),l){var j=h.find(".clockpicker-canvas"),L=t("svg");L.setAttribute("class","clockpicker-svg"),L.setAttribute("width",M),L.setAttribute("height",M);var U=t("g");U.setAttribute("transform","translate("+b+","+b+")");var W=t("circle");W.setAttribute("class","clockpicker-canvas-bearing"),W.setAttribute("cx",0),W.setAttribute("cy",0),W.setAttribute("r",2);var N=t("line");N.setAttribute("x1",0),N.setAttribute("y1",0);var X=t("circle");X.setAttribute("class","clockpicker-canvas-bg"),X.setAttribute("r",y);var Y=t("circle");Y.setAttribute("class","clockpicker-canvas-fg"),Y.setAttribute("r",3.5),U.appendChild(N),U.appendChild(X),U.appendChild(Y),U.appendChild(W),L.appendChild(U),j.append(L),this.hand=N,this.bg=X,this.fg=Y,this.bearing=W,this.g=U,this.canvas=j}o(this.options.init)}function o(t){t&&"function"==typeof t&&t()}var c,n=window.jQuery,r=n(window),a=n(document),p="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",l="SVGAngle"in window&&function(){var t,i=document.createElement("div");return i.innerHTML="<svg/>",t=(i.firstChild&&i.firstChild.namespaceURI)==p,i.innerHTML="",t}(),h=function(){var t=document.createElement("div").style;return"transition"in t||"WebkitTransition"in t||"MozTransition"in t||"msTransition"in t||"OTransition"in t}(),u="ontouchstart"in window,k="mousedown"+(u?" touchstart":""),d="mousemove.clockpicker"+(u?" touchmove.clockpicker":""),f="mouseup.clockpicker"+(u?" touchend.clockpicker":""),v=navigator.vibrate?"vibrate":navigator.webkitVibrate?"webkitVibrate":null,m=0,b=100,g=80,w=54,y=13,M=2*b,A=h?350:1,V=['<div class="popover clockpicker-popover">','<div class="arrow"></div>','<div class="popover-title">','<span class="clockpicker-span-hours text-primary"></span>'," : ",'<span class="clockpicker-span-minutes"></span>','<span class="clockpicker-span-am-pm"></span>',"</div>",'<div class="popover-content">','<div class="clockpicker-plate">','<div class="clockpicker-canvas"></div>','<div class="clockpicker-dial clockpicker-hours"></div>','<div class="clockpicker-dial clockpicker-minutes clockpicker-dial-out"></div>',"</div>",'<span class="clockpicker-am-pm-block">',"</span>","</div>","</div>"].join("");s.DEFAULTS={"default":"",fromnow:0,placement:"bottom",align:"left",donetext:"完成",autoclose:!1,twelvehour:!1,vibrate:!0},s.prototype.toggle=function(){this[this.isShown?"hide":"show"]()},s.prototype.locate=function(){var t=this.element,i=this.popover,e=t.offset(),s=t.outerWidth(),o=t.outerHeight(),c=this.options.placement,n=this.options.align,r={};switch(i.show(),c){case"bottom":r.top=e.top+o;break;case"right":r.left=e.left+s;break;case"top":r.top=e.top-i.outerHeight();break;case"left":r.left=e.left-i.outerWidth()}switch(n){case"left":r.left=e.left;break;case"right":r.left=e.left+s-i.outerWidth();break;case"top":r.top=e.top;break;case"bottom":r.top=e.top+o-i.outerHeight()}i.css(r)},s.prototype.show=function(){if(!this.isShown){o(this.options.beforeShow);var t=this;this.isAppended||(c=n(document.body).append(this.popover),r.on("resize.clockpicker"+this.id,function(){t.isShown&&t.locate()}),this.isAppended=!0);var e=((this.input.prop("value")||this.options["default"]||"")+"").split(":");if("now"===e[0]){var s=new Date(+new Date+this.options.fromnow);e=[s.getHours(),s.getMinutes()]}this.hours=+e[0]||0,this.minutes=+e[1]||0,this.spanHours.html(i(this.hours)),this.spanMinutes.html(i(this.minutes)),this.toggleView("hours"),this.locate(),this.isShown=!0,a.on("click.clockpicker."+this.id+" focusin.clockpicker."+this.id,function(i){var e=n(i.target);0===e.closest(t.popover).length&&0===e.closest(t.addon).length&&0===e.closest(t.input).length&&t.hide()}),a.on("keyup.clockpicker."+this.id,function(i){27===i.keyCode&&t.hide()}),o(this.options.afterShow)}},s.prototype.hide=function(){o(this.options.beforeHide),this.isShown=!1,a.off("click.clockpicker."+this.id+" focusin.clockpicker."+this.id),a.off("keyup.clockpicker."+this.id),this.popover.hide(),o(this.options.afterHide)},s.prototype.toggleView=function(t,i){var e=!1;"minutes"===t&&"visible"===n(this.hoursView).css("visibility")&&(o(this.options.beforeHourSelect),e=!0);var s="hours"===t,c=s?this.hoursView:this.minutesView,r=s?this.minutesView:this.hoursView;this.currentView=t,this.spanHours.toggleClass("text-primary",s),this.spanMinutes.toggleClass("text-primary",!s),r.addClass("clockpicker-dial-out"),c.css("visibility","visible").removeClass("clockpicker-dial-out"),this.resetClock(i),clearTimeout(this.toggleViewTimer),this.toggleViewTimer=setTimeout(function(){r.css("visibility","hidden")},A),e&&o(this.options.afterHourSelect)},s.prototype.resetClock=function(t){var i=this.currentView,e=this[i],s="hours"===i,o=Math.PI/(s?6:30),c=e*o,n=s&&e>0&&13>e?w:g,r=Math.sin(c)*n,a=-Math.cos(c)*n,p=this;l&&t?(p.canvas.addClass("clockpicker-canvas-out"),setTimeout(function(){p.canvas.removeClass("clockpicker-canvas-out"),p.setHand(r,a)},t)):this.setHand(r,a)},s.prototype.setHand=function(t,e,s,o){var c,r=Math.atan2(t,-e),a="hours"===this.currentView,p=Math.PI/(a||s?6:30),h=Math.sqrt(t*t+e*e),u=this.options,k=a&&(g+w)/2>h,d=k?w:g;if(u.twelvehour&&(d=g),0>r&&(r=2*Math.PI+r),c=Math.round(r/p),r=c*p,u.twelvehour?a?0===c&&(c=12):(s&&(c*=5),60===c&&(c=0)):a?(12===c&&(c=0),c=k?0===c?12:c:0===c?0:c+12):(s&&(c*=5),60===c&&(c=0)),this[this.currentView]!==c&&v&&this.options.vibrate&&(this.vibrateTimer||(navigator[v](10),this.vibrateTimer=setTimeout(n.proxy(function(){this.vibrateTimer=null},this),100))),this[this.currentView]=c,this[a?"spanHours":"spanMinutes"].html(i(c)),!l)return void this[a?"hoursView":"minutesView"].find(".clockpicker-tick").each(function(){var t=n(this);t.toggleClass("active",c===+t.html())});o||!a&&c%5?(this.g.insertBefore(this.hand,this.bearing),this.g.insertBefore(this.bg,this.fg),this.bg.setAttribute("class","clockpicker-canvas-bg clockpicker-canvas-bg-trans")):(this.g.insertBefore(this.hand,this.bg),this.g.insertBefore(this.fg,this.bg),this.bg.setAttribute("class","clockpicker-canvas-bg"));var f=Math.sin(r)*d,m=-Math.cos(r)*d;this.hand.setAttribute("x2",f),this.hand.setAttribute("y2",m),this.bg.setAttribute("cx",f),this.bg.setAttribute("cy",m),this.fg.setAttribute("cx",f),this.fg.setAttribute("cy",m)},s.prototype.done=function(){o(this.options.beforeDone),this.hide();var t=this.input.prop("value"),e=i(this.hours)+":"+i(this.minutes);this.options.twelvehour&&(e+=this.amOrPm),this.input.prop("value",e),e!==t&&(this.input.triggerHandler("change"),this.isInput||this.element.trigger("change")),this.options.autoclose&&this.input.trigger("blur"),o(this.options.afterDone)},s.prototype.remove=function(){this.element.removeData("clockpicker"),this.input.off("focus.clockpicker click.clockpicker"),this.addon.off("click.clockpicker"),this.isShown&&this.hide(),this.isAppended&&(r.off("resize.clockpicker"+this.id),this.popover.remove())},n.fn.clockpicker=function(t){var i=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return this.each(function(){var e=n(this),o=e.data("clockpicker");if(o)"function"==typeof o[t]&&o[t].apply(o,i);else{var c=n.extend({},s.DEFAULTS,e.data(),"object"==typeof t&&t);e.data("clockpicker",new s(e,c))}})}}();
```

jquery-clockpicker.min.css.html

```
 /*!
 * ClockPicker v0.0.7 for jQuery (http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)
 * Copyright 2014 Wang Shenwei.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 * 
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */.popover{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1010;display:none;max-width:276px;padding:1px;text-align:left;white-space:normal;background-color:#fff;background-clip:padding-box;border:1px solid #ccc;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius:6px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.popover.top{margin-top:-10px}.popover.right{margin-left:10px}.popover.bottom{margin-top:10px}.popover.left{margin-left:-10px}.popover-title{padding:8px 14px;margin:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:18px;background-color:#f7f7f7;border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;border-radius:5px 5px 0 0}.popover-content{padding:9px 14px}.popover>.arrow,.popover>.arrow:after{position:absolute;display:block;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;overflow:visible;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:auto;background-color:transparent;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;bottom:auto;left:auto;right:auto;top:auto;-webkit-transform:none;-ms-transform:none;transform:none}.popover>.arrow{border-width:11px}.popover>.arrow:after{content:"";border-width:10px}.popover.top>.arrow{bottom:-11px;left:50%;margin-left:-11px;border-top-color:#999;border-top-color:rgba(0,0,0,.25);border-bottom-width:0}.popover.top>.arrow:after{bottom:1px;margin-left:-10px;content:" ";border-top-color:#fff;border-bottom-width:0}.popover.right>.arrow{top:50%;left:-11px;margin-top:-11px;border-right-color:#999;border-right-color:rgba(0,0,0,.25);border-left-width:0}.popover.right>.arrow:after{bottom:-10px;left:1px;content:" ";border-right-color:#fff;border-left-width:0}.popover.bottom>.arrow{top:-11px;left:50%;margin-left:-11px;border-top-width:0;border-bottom-color:#999;border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0,.25)}.popover.bottom>.arrow:after{top:1px;margin-left:-10px;content:" ";border-top-width:0;border-bottom-color:#fff}.popover.left>.arrow{top:50%;right:-11px;margin-top:-11px;border-right-width:0;border-left-color:#999;border-left-color:rgba(0,0,0,.25)}.popover.left>.arrow:after{right:1px;bottom:-10px;content:" ";border-right-width:0;border-left-color:#fff}.btn{cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;background-image:none;border:1px solid transparent}.btn.active:focus,.btn:active:focus,.btn:focus{outline:dotted thin;outline:-webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;outline-offset:-2px}.btn:focus,.btn:hover{color:#333;text-decoration:none}.btn.active,.btn:active{background-image:none;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125)}.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#fff;border-color:#ccc}.btn-default.active,.btn-default:active,.btn-default:focus,.btn-default:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#ebebeb;border-color:#adadad}.btn-default.active,.btn-default:active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default{background-image:none}.btn-block{display:block;width:100%}.text-primary{color:#428bca}.clockpicker .input-group-addon{cursor:pointer}.clockpicker-moving{cursor:move}.clockpicker-align-left.popover>.arrow{left:25px}.clockpicker-align-top.popover>.arrow{top:17px}.clockpicker-align-right.popover>.arrow{left:auto;right:25px}.clockpicker-align-bottom.popover>.arrow{top:auto;bottom:6px}.clockpicker-popover .popover-title{background-color:#fff;color:#999;font-size:24px;font-weight:700;line-height:30px;text-align:center}.clockpicker-popover .popover-title span{cursor:pointer}.clockpicker-popover .popover-content{background-color:#f8f8f8;padding:12px}.popover-content:last-child{border-bottom-left-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px}.clockpicker-plate{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:50%;width:200px;height:200px;overflow:visible;position:relative;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.clockpicker-canvas,.clockpicker-dial{width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;left:-1px;top:-1px}.clockpicker-minutes{visibility:hidden}.clockpicker-tick{border-radius:50%;color:#666;line-height:26px;text-align:center;width:26px;height:26px;position:absolute;cursor:pointer}.clockpicker-tick.active,.clockpicker-tick:hover{background-color:#c0e5f7;background-color:rgba(0,149,221,.25)}.clockpicker-button{background-image:none;background-color:#fff;border-width:1px 0 0;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0;margin:0;padding:10px 0}.clockpicker-button:hover{background-image:none;background-color:#ebebeb}.clockpicker-button:focus{outline:0!important}.clockpicker-dial{-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 350ms,opacity 350ms;-moz-transition:-moz-transform 350ms,opacity 350ms;-ms-transition:-ms-transform 350ms,opacity 350ms;-o-transition:-o-transform 350ms,opacity 350ms;transition:transform 350ms,opacity 350ms}.clockpicker-dial-out{opacity:0}.clockpicker-hours.clockpicker-dial-out{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2,1.2);-moz-transform:scale(1.2,1.2);-ms-transform:scale(1.2,1.2);-o-transform:scale(1.2,1.2);transform:scale(1.2,1.2)}.clockpicker-minutes.clockpicker-dial-out{-webkit-transform:scale(.8,.8);-moz-transform:scale(.8,.8);-ms-transform:scale(.8,.8);-o-transform:scale(.8,.8);transform:scale(.8,.8)}.clockpicker-canvas{-webkit-transition:opacity 175ms;-moz-transition:opacity 175ms;-ms-transition:opacity 175ms;-o-transition:opacity 175ms;transition:opacity 175ms}.clockpicker-canvas-out{opacity:.25}.clockpicker-canvas-bearing,.clockpicker-canvas-fg{stroke:none;fill:#0095dd}.clockpicker-canvas-bg{stroke:none;fill:#c0e5f7}.clockpicker-canvas-bg-trans{fill:rgba(0,149,221,.25)}.clockpicker-canvas line{stroke:#0095dd;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round}.clockpicker-button.am-button{margin:1px;padding:5px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius:4px}.clockpicker-button.pm-button{margin:1px 1px 1px 136px;padding:5px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius:4px}
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

### Edit

I followed the suggestion of Liverpool Coder to change the references to HTTPS directly to the distribution site. Now, the attached image shows the output:

[image]

JavaScript works but CSS does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems that the issue with the JSFiddle is because it is trying to grab the colour picker js files using HTTP but the file has to be loaded using HTTPS.

I would recommend you swap out the following lines

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquerclockpicker.min.js').getContent(); ?>
```

for

```
<script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
```

and do the same with the CSS file

I used the url for the example above and it works but you should point to the local file

Comment: Thanks, Liverpool Coder! I changed the references like you said, and now the tool is operating! However, the css file does not seem to render as I was expecting it to. It only shows two black dots. I've uploaded an image of what I mean to my original post. To be clear, I got rid of the <? ?> GAS statements and instead wrote: <script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css"></script> and <script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.js"></script>. Is that right?

Comment: Upload a plunk of the new issue and I will try help you out with it

Comment: In fact I think what you need to do is probably just change again the "<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquery-clockpicker.min.css').getContent(); ?>"  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-clockpicker.min.css"> to the path to your local version of the css file

Comment: I should also mention the dev console says:  uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . (jquery-clockpicker.min.css:9). Thanks so much!

Comment: SPECTACULAR! Thanks for the help so much! Consider question answered!

Comment: Thank you. Can you click the tick next to my answer.

Comment: Also i mentioned in the answer to link to the URL but you should be able to just point to your local version as well